# Can CircleCI be used with Microsoft TFS (Visual Studio)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfs, circleci

I'm using microsoft TFS and I want to make continuous deployment on AWS using CircleCI.. Is that possible? if not, what should I exactly do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid not, CircleCI  is just a continuous integration tools which TFS could also do the CI and include some useful task easily enable build and release pipelines.

You could use **[AWS Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools)**.

This tool include a new service endpoint type, *AWS*, to supply AWS credentials to the tasks at runtime.

It will create an AWS Credentials Connection. Select the AWS endpoint type and provide the following parameters:

- A name used to refer to the credentials when configuring tasks that
  require AWS credentials
- AWS Access Key ID
- AWS Secret Access Key

[image]

After an AWS subscription has be linked to Team Foundation Server, you could use the task deploy to Amazon EC2 with AWS CodeDeploy.

*Note: Minimum supported environments*

- Visual Studio Team Services
- Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3 (or higher)